# How to set/display select options in selectbox using form-api 

Tags: 6, forms

I have created a form to allow users to enter some details but I also need to display some mysql data into that form. The contents and fields of the form are displayed in a tabular format. I just want to know the right way to display mysql data in one of the table columns along with the form fields. 
How can i display select options in selectbox using form-api ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`theme_table`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/6) to make a table view. 
You can use [`form-api`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6) inside the table as you wish.

Sample code for creating table.

```
$header = array();
$rows = array();
$rows[] = array(
    array('data' => 'Head1', 'rowspan'=> 2, 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'Head2', 'rowspan'=> 2, 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'Head3', 'rowspan'=> 2, 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'Head4', 'rowspan'=> 2, 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'Head5', 'rowspan'=> 2, 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'Head6', 'colspan'=> 6, 'header' => 1),
);
$rows[] = array(
    array('data' => 'SubHead6-1', 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'SubHead6-2', 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'SubHead6-3', 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'SubHead6-4', 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'SubHead6-5', 'header' => 1),
    array('data' => 'SubHead6-6', 'header' => 1),
);
```

return  `$output .= theme('table', $header, $rows);`

To make a select box with db values you can try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {tablemanme}";
$query_result =  db_query($query);
while (($data = db_fetch_object($query_result )) !== FALSE) {
  $opt[$data->id] = $data->name;
}

$form['select'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $opt,
);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Hi my from fields are displaying in a tabular format but I am not able to display mysql data in the form

Comment: @SomyaGupta, What type of mysql data? Do you want to display it inside the form fields?

Comment: yes I want college names to be displayed as a form field within a table cell So the student can make a selection

Comment: @SomyaGupta, See my edit.

Answer (score -2):

You can check on this link

- http://public-action.org/content/drupal-7-form-api-drupal-7-multi-step-form-fapi-table-report

  It gives you complete idea of displaying data in tabular form

Comment: OP is talking about D6

Comment: that's true, but in fact form API in D7 is 95% the same as the one in D6.